# how to customized labellist of an recharts bar graph

Tags: reactjs, recharts

[image]

I want to remove 0 from Mar, and Apr based on some condition for that I need to send the x-axis values that is months value so that I can compare them and customize the label.

```
                     <Bar
                        dataKey="month"
                        stackId="month"
                        fill="#ff9800"
                        style={{ fontSize: '9px' }} >
                        <LabelList                           
                          content={(content) => <CustomLabel value={content}/>}
                        />
                      </Bar>
```

is there a way from that we can pass x-axis value to the LabelList component?